# Using Squeak from a shell

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo

Can I launch Squeak as a REPL (no GUI), where I can enter and evaluate Smalltalk expressions? I know the default image don't allow this. Is there any documentation on how to build a minimum image that can be accessed from a command-line shell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a (hackish) solution:
First, you need OSProcess, so run this in a Workspace:

```
Gofer new squeaksource:'OSProcess'; package:'OSProcess';load.
```

Next, put this in the file repl.st:

```
OSProcess thisOSProcess stdOut 
  nextPutAll: 'Welcome to the simple Smalltalk REPL'; 
  nextPut: Character lf; nextPut: $>; flush.
[ |input|
  [ input := OSProcess readFromStdIn.
    input size > 0 ifTrue: [
      OSProcess thisOSProcess stdOut 
        nextPutAll: ((Compiler evaluate: input) asString; 
        nextPut: Character lf; nextPut: $>; flush 
    ]
  ] repeat.
]forkAt: (Processor userBackgroundPriority)
```

And last, run this command:

```
squeak -headless path/to/squeak.image /absolute/path/to/repl.st
```

You can now have fun with a Smalltalk REPL. Dont forget to type in the command:

```
Smalltalk snapshot:true andQuit:true
```

if you want to save your changes.

Now, onto the explanation of this solution:
OSProcess is a package that allows to run other processes, read from stdin, and write to stdout and stderr. You can access the stdout AttachableFileStream with `OSProcess thisOSProcess` (the current process, aka squeak).

Next, you run an infinite loop at userBackgroundPriority (to let other processes run). In this infinite loop, you use `Compiler evaluate:` to execute the input.

And you run this in a script with a headless image.

Answer (score 9):

As of Pharo 2.0 (and 1.3/1.4 with the fix described below), there are no more hacks necessary. The following snippet will turn your vanilla Pharo image into a REPL server...

From https://gist.github.com/2604215:

```
"Works out of the box in Pharo 2.0. For prior versions (definitely works in 1.3 and 1.4), first file in https://gist.github.com/2602113"

| command |
[
    command := FileStream stdin nextLine.
    command ~= 'exit' ] whileTrue: [ | result |
        result := Compiler evaluate: command.
        FileStream stdout nextPutAll: result asString; lf ].

Smalltalk snapshot: false andQuit: true.
```

If you want the image to always be a REPL, put the code in a #startup: method; otherwise, pass the script at the command line when you want REPL mode, like:

```
"/path/to/vm" -headless "/path/to/Pharo-2.0.image" "/path/to/gistfile1.st"
```

Answer (score 7):

Please visit:
http://map.squeak.org/package/2c3b916b-75e2-455b-b25d-eba1bbc94b84
and [Run Smalltalk on server without GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443281/run-smalltalk-on-server-without-gui)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The first link is basically unrelated to the question. The second is to a question about server operation. But this question, as I understand it, is about running Squeak like `irb` or `python` so that it interacts with the terminal on stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The project http://www.squeaksource.com/SecureSqueak.html includes a REPL package that may provide much of what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh and the first link in Friedrich's response includes reference to ExternalCommandShell which sounds like it provides similar functionality.

Comment: More information about REPLServer from SecureSqueak can be found at http://gulik.pbworks.com/w/page/7760030/REPLServer .