# Can I use interactive command line for Squeak/Pharo development?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, command-line-interface

I tried to install Squeak/Pharo into Ubuntu server machine.

```
./squeak -vm-display-null ./Pharo-1.2.2-12353/Pharo-1.2.image
```

It executed, but there was no command-line. No way to use without GUI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067563/using-squeak-from-a-shell

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Coral, it provides a scripting interface to Pharo. Not sure where to find up-to-date documentation, but there is a build on the [Pharo Build Server](https://pharo-ic.lille.inria.fr/hudson/job/Pharo%20Coral/).

Comment: Based on its dependencies (OSProcess, PetitSmalltalk, PetitParser, AST-Core) Coral should also work in Squeak.

Comment: Coral looks great, but it's hard to setup. I followed the instructions but $ coral.sh scriptHello.cst does nothing--no errors, no warnings. This thing needs installers.

Answer (score 3):

You can send scripts by parameter to the VM.

```
          ./squeak -vm-display-null ./Pharo-1.2.2-12353/Pharo-1.2.image myScript.st
```

But that's all you can do apart from Coral. Otherwise you should use GNUSmalltalk

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the current VM you have to use a full "file:///" URL, a choice made a while back and only recently having been discussed as wanting to be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your needs correctly, but I guess you could write a few liner read-eval loop, and pass it as script argument at start up.

Other than that most headless usages of smalltalk are for web servers (seaside, aida), in which case there is usually an admin url which lets you to poke around image by sending messages to objects and similar. If you have seaside one click image you could try out:

http://localhost:8080/tools/classbrowser

http://localhost:8080/tools/screenshot

http://localhost:8080/tools/versionuploader

to give you a taste of what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is Coral, but you might also look into a lighter version of Pharo called "Pharo Kernel":

> Pharo Kernel is a small Smalltalk kernel that is stripped down from Pharo Core image. Meanwhile there is also a 3MB Pharo-Kernel-Gofer image available that has networking support and Gofer (a pharo installer to load packages) installed.

Check it out at https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/view/Pharo-Kernel-2.0/job/PharoKernel2.0/