# How to install OSProcess in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I want to use OSProcess to execute external programs in Linux and MacOS from Pharo 1.4. I've followed [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067563/using-squeak-from-a-shell) install instructions but when I evaluate

```
(PipeableOSProcess command: 'pwd') output asFileReference
```

it hangs the VM under Ubuntu. For OSProcessPlugin There is a [Squeak](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/3349) wiki page with instructions but execution returns:

> OSProcess not available or OSProcess plugin not functioning

Loading [OSProcess sar file](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/708) from the File Browser leads to a Syntax Error

```
(anArrayOfNullTerminatedStrings collect: [:e | e size])
    inject: offset into: [:p :e | ws nextPut: p. Cannot store into -> p := p + e].
```

Do I have to build my own VM to make it work?
What do I need to do to execute commands in Linux under latest Pharo 1.4?

Comment: Please note that question and answers are dated, and no longer apply to the newer Pharo versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Pharo book](http://book.pharo-project.org/book/PharoTools/OSProcess/) (read it!)

```
Gofer new
    squeaksource3: 'coral';
    package: 'OSProcess'; 
    load.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the Configuration for OSProcess available in the Metacello Repository:

```
Gofer new
    squeaksource: 'MetacelloRepository';
    package: 'ConfigurationOfOSProcess';
    load.

((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfOSProcess) project version: #stable) load.
```

Using the configuration you avoid loading unstable versions.

Answer (score 2):

In Pharo 5.0 or alpha 6, use the Catalog Browser, found in the Tools menu of the world menu.

[image: Screenshot of Pharo window]